# How to manually refresh an extjs app rather than let sencha cmd app watch command do it automatically?

Tags: extjs, sencha-cmd

Until now we are using the following command to develop our extjs apps: `sencha app watch classic` or `sencha app watch modern`

Because `sencha app watch` has the effect to reload every time a save occurs, we do not want this effect anymore.

Which are the commands to manually do in steps what `sencha app watch` does ?

We read the reference of sencha cmd: https://docs.sencha.com/cmd/6.x/advanced_cmd/cmd_reference.html#sencha_app_build

After reading it we thought that if we execute `sencha app refresh classic` and then execute `sencha web start` would be the solution to what we are looking for: to manually refresh the app rather let sencha app watch do it automatically all of the time.

Unfortunately these two commands are not correct or not enough because the app does not load using them.

Comment: Well, I am using Ctrl+R ("force reload") in my favorite browser...

Comment: What do you mean?... We do not want to use sencha app watch command at all

Comment: Version number of extjs: 6.0.2. Version number of sencha cmd: 6.1.2.15

Answer (score 0):

You can use simply **sencha app refresh** .

Also when you post please mention verison number of Ext JS.

Comment: could you express the full set of commands that are needed? Thank you